# Solana getBalance() fetch failed on AWS Lambda

Tags: wallet, balance

As the title suggests, I need to make an **AWS Lambda** function which retrieves an account balance.

Tha problem is that it often throws the error:

```
INFO    Error: failed to get balance of account 4pZWvfQZWAYDxMCoGhMhySURo3JCriXB2CUUqhXyKF1H: TypeError: fetch failed
    at /opt/nodejs/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6006:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:449:9)
    at async Connection.getBalance (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6005:12)
    at async /var/task/bot.js:43:30
    at async execute (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/telegraf/lib/composer.js:501:17)
    at async /opt/nodejs/node_modules/telegraf/lib/composer.js:502:21
    at async execute (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/telegraf/lib/composer.js:501:17)
    at async /opt/nodejs/node_modules/telegraf/lib/composer.js:502:21
2024-02-10T13:05:21.558Z 7429f075-092d-4bbe-8dbf-7de887ef3e55 INFO Error: failed to get balance of account 4pZWvfQZWAYDxMCoGhMhySURo3JCriXB2CUUqhXyKF1H: TypeError: fetch failed at /opt/nodejs/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6006:13 at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3) at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:449:9) at async Connection.getBalance (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6005:12) at async /var/task/bot.js:43:30 at async execute (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/telegraf/lib/composer.js:501:17) at async /opt/nodejs/node_modules/telegraf/lib/composer.js:502:21 at async execute (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/telegraf/lib/composer.js:501:17) at async /opt/nodejs/node_modules/telegraf/lib/composer.js:502:21
```

This is the simple line which is raising the error:

```
const balance = (await new Connection(process.env.SOLANA_HTTPS).getBalance(new PublicKey("4pZWvfQZWAYDxMCoGhMhySURo3JCriXB2CUUqhXyKF1H"))) / 10**9;
```

I'm stuck on this and I cannot get the problem with **AWS Lambda**.
Locally, it works great!

Thank you in advance

Comment: The error is not really Solana specific. It means either you have network issue or nodejs verson issue. Are you sure you are using the latest Node.js version which supports `fetch`? Also, make sure your network and firewall settings allow requests. You can test it out by making a simply GET request to any public API.